# EOMONTH returns the 1st day of the next month for months with 30 days

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

When I use the formula below the results of the EOMONTH function
returns the start of the next month for any month with 30 days instead of the last day of the specified month. The month and years are correct, so I'm pretty sure it's EOMONTH when used in another function.
For example,the results in B3 should be "11/31/1965" but it returns "12/1/1965".

> =DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(TEXT(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))))

[image: First formula with incorrect date]

I have tried subtracting a day, but it returns the end-of-month -1 for months with 31 days (30). So I have the same problem in the other case.

I have also used IFS() to account for months with 30 days, and it miscalculates the date the same way.

> =IFS( MONTH(B2)+6  = 4,DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))-2)  ,
> MONTH(B2)+6  =
> 6,DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))-2)  ,
> MONTH(B2)+6  =
> 9,DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))-2)  ,
> MONTH(B2)+6 =
> 11,DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))-2)  ,
> TRUE    ,DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+6,DAY(EOMONTH(MONTH(B2)+6,0))  ) )

The EOMONTH function by itself where I just pass in the date as a string works correctly (column F).

Any Idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @player0 has explained, you can't just add something to a month and feed it into eomonth. Try putting

```
=eomonth(month(B2)+6,0)
```

into B3 (formatted as a date).

You get

```
1/31/1900
```

Why? month(b2)+6 gives 11 (which is just a number). Dates in google sheets are represented as days since 12/31/1899. So 11 formatted as a date gives 1/11/1900. Applying eomonth to that gives the last day of January 1900, which is the 31st. Feeding that into your formula would give 11/31/65, but that date doesn't exist, so you get 12/1/65.

If you want to go forward 6 months and then get the last day of the month, you need

```
=eomonth(date(year(B2),month(B2)+6,1),0)
```

[image]

You can also use the Edate function, which does not roll over into the first day of the next month:

```
=eomonth(edate(B2,6),0)
```

Comment: Thank you and player0! Understanding what EOMONTH was returning and the detailed explanation are great and I am grteful for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`EOMONTH` does not understand `MONTH`. instead, it converts it into date. to use `EOMONTH` you need to supply it with valid date

```
=EOMONTH(B2, 0)
```